# Immutable object with side effect

Tags: java, oop, immutability

Let consider immutable object `File` which encapsulates `fileName` which points to file on the disk. That object has method `rename` which is obviously assign new name to the file on the disk.

```
public final class File {

   private final String fileName;

   public File(String fileName fileName) {
       this.fileName = fileName;
   }

   public File rename(String newName) {
        // Rename the actual file on the disk (code is omitted)
        // and that is the side effect!
        return new File(newName);
   }
}
```

So the questions are:

- How to approach side effects with immutable objects? Our `File` object once created should be working always with the same encapsulated state. And return new object with modified state. This is perfectly done in `java.lang.String` class. But the old object (which is still point to **wrong** `fileName`) is not good. We can't use it as state is broken.
- Does it means that object is not truly immutable? And what if we want to work only with true immutable objects with consistent state? We shouldn't rename file on the disk? But how to get the job done when we actually need file to be renamed?

Assume that `File` is only an example.

Comment: since you can not destroy the object, you just need to wait until the old object is eligible to be GarbageCollected

Comment: Why do you think the old filename is "**wrong**"? it is as valid as it was before the renaming. Just the file it points to (an object in the file-system) does not exists...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto because I can't reuse that particular object. It is modified state with side effect. And even worse: all of the properties of the old `File` are stays the same as object is immutable. So the whole object is broken. but i got your point. technically speaking - yes. Object is still manageble but don't usefull. And still it is not the same as it was when created. So is it really immutable?

Comment: Certainly you can reuse it. A `File` represents a file *name*, not a file, and file names don't have to exist.

Comment: What properties have a "filename" does?

Comment: Let me clarify. We should be able to reuse object **safely**. Which means that if it had a state, it should be the same. But it is not the case with *side effect*. That the question is about. Side effect effectivily affects state and state is not correlated to what it suppose to be from the creation. It is not just about technically reusing just by means of the attributes.

Comment: Immutability means the object doesn't encapsulate internal state. It says nothing about the validity of the data it holds with regard to external state. If have a `String username = "shmosel";` and tomorrow I change my username, that doesn't mean strings are now mutable. The value has just become obsolete.

Comment: I believe the problem is with the choice of representing an actually mutable thing (a file) as an immutable object (the state of the file isn't something we can control, the file could well be deleted by another process/user). If you wanted the immutable object to always stay valid, then you'd need to obtain a lock on that file during object creation AND while renaming, you'd need to create a new cloned file with the new name. That would do it with few exceptions (like a super-user could still modify that file I guess)

Comment: @AshutoshA yes, exactly that is the problem. We might have some actual mutable thing but we want to write immutable code.

Comment: Right. But then that's just not possible. Given the scenario and requirement, you can't make these objects 100% immutable. You can still strive to make the state as immutable as possible, but then that's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to approach side effects with immutable objects? Our File object once created should be working always with the same encapsulated state. And return new object with modified state. This is perfectly done in java.lang.String class. But the old object (which is still point to wrong fileName) is not good. We can't use it as state is broken.

Your example has one issue, which is not possible to overcome. Your side effect, this part of code, is not in your control:

```
    // Rename the actual file on the disk (code is omitted)
    // and that is the side effect!
```

In case of String, you have every byte of the string under your control, so you can guarantee the purity for the methods on the String. In case of your File example, there is also an environment involved - operating system, where this file exists or not. Even if it exists, it may be not accessible to your process. There may be plenty of reasons why you cannot actually rename the file.

IMO it is not possible to overcome this. World around you is not pure - your code executes on system with lots of side effects and mutability. Your disk is stateful, your RAM is not constant. Even in Haskell the function `renameFile :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO ()` from https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.1.1/docs/System-Directory.html is not ideally pure - it can cause errors in some cases.

But it is not the reason to think that the object is invalid. As it was already said in comments, you encapsulated the file name, not the file descriptor. So, your File represents valid file name. Probably the question is more about validity of the renaming method?

> Does it means that object is not truly immutable? And what if we want to work only with true immutable objects with consistent state? We shouldn't rename file on the disk? But how to get the job done when we actually need file to be renamed?

It is immutable. The call `rename` on this object is not pure, that's all. *Immutability* and *Purity* are different terms. Your object may be immutable and still have side effects, like in your example.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "purity", but in Java "pure" already has a meaning: it is the opposite of "native".

Comment: I meant what I meant. Nuff said.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you should read the next article: http://www.yegor256.com/2016/09/07/gradients-of-immutability.html
because Immutability is nor black or white